# NGINX with mono and fastcgi-mono-server4.exe in windows

Tags: asp.net, windows, nginx, mono

For academic purposes i am trying to set up the Nginx with mono on my dev. machine (Windows 7).

I got stuck at one point and not sure how to proceed.

1. Installed Nginx and configured it to run on a different port and its working fine. can browse localhost and everything is working fine.
2. Installed Mono and it installed properly under system root.

One thing i am not sure was as referenced in most of the documents is to start the fastcgi-mono-server4.exe that way the asp.net files gets executed and i cant find that file. Where and how to download that file and install it in windows so that i can run it and hence can start nginx?

All the documents point to installing it on a Linux but as said earlier trying to set this on a windows 7 machine.

Please let me know how i can achieve this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

FYI... this is the document i was referring to http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/fastcgi/nginx/ and it mentions in the last section to start the Mono FastCGI server.

Thanks,
Bobby

Comment: So is it not possible to install fastcgi-mono-server on windows? I havent seen any one replying to this question. I would love to install the server and test it.

Comment: take a look at this: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/fastcgi/ there shows you how to install it, but I velive you will need to compile it from source

Comment: @Gusman Thanks for the reply.. i have checked that document earlier. This is what it says "This documentation contains configuration instructions for serveral web servers on Linux, with plans to expand support to Windows and Macintosh in the future." But i have seen some forums with people mentioning the fast cgi server on Windows i.e their file is on c:\program Files\mono\... FYI i was able to install this on a Ubuntu and configured nginx to run asp.net websites without any trouble. Problem is with the windows installation. How can ii compile it for windows?